# JSON deserializing not happening

Tags: apex, lightning, deserialize

I'm trying to deserialize a `List of JSON objects` in `Apex`. Here is the JSON being passed:

```
[
 {
  "Name":"TestUser1",
  "Interview_Information":{
     "Interviewer":"JTA Test",
     "CandidateStage":"Final ROund",
     "Recommendation":"Hire!",
     "Candidate_Name":"JTA Test",
     "Competency":[
        {
           "Competency":"Team Player",
           "Question":"Describe when you failed on a team",
           "Rating":"Advanced",
           "Candidate_Name":"JTA Test"
        }
     ]
  }
 }
]
```

And here is my APEX code :

```
public class DeserializeJSON {
 public String PDFData {get; set;}

 public DeserializeJSON() {
    PDFData = '';
 }

 public void deserialize() {
   List<DeserializeJSON.CandidateSummary> allCandidates = (List<DeserializeJSON.CandidateSummary>)JSON.deserialize(PDFData, List<DeserializeJSON.CandidateSummary>.class);
    system.debug('allCandidates = '+allCandidates);
 }

public class CandidateSummary {
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public Interview_Information Interview_Information {get; set;}
}

public class Interview_Information {
    public String Interviewer;
    public String CandidateStage;
    public String Recommendation;
    public String Candidate_Name;
    public List<Competency> Competency;
}

public class Competency {
    public String Competency;
    public String Question;
    public String Rating;
    public String Candidate_Name;
}
```

UPDATE :
I updated my code as per the SFDC's suggestion -- none of my debug statements are showing up on dev console now.

Comment: This is fine, if you are not getting the debug statements then it seems like you are not calling the `DeserializeJSON.deserialize()` method from anywhere.
`DeserializeJSON deserializeJSON = new DeserializeJSON();
deserializeJSON.PDFData = YOUR_JSON;
deserializeJSON.deserialize();
`
And this method doesn't return anything as of now, I guess you need to adjust the return type as well.

Comment: Can you just more specify your requirement? do you just want to deserializeJSON.. thats it??

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 The function is being called as the debug statements were showing up before I made changes as per the changes suggested by sfdcfox - I'm confused as to why the debug line stopped showing up on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Interview_Information is another object. Here's what you'd change:

```
public class Interview {
    public String Name;
    public Interview_Information Interview_Information;
}
public class Interview_Information {
    public String Interviewer;
    public String CandidateStage;
    public String Recommendation;
    public String Candidate_Name;
    public List<Competency> Competency;
}
public class Competency {
    public String Competency;
    public String Question;
    public String Rating;
    public String Candidate_Name;
}
```

And:

```
List<DataDisplayController.Interview> allCandidates = (List<DataDisplayController.Interview>)JSON.deserialize(PDFData, List<DataDisplayController.Interview>.class);
```

Comment: I tried it this way as well and it didn't work. None of my debug statements display on the console so I assume it's incorrect. Let me update my code above @sfdcfox

Comment: @user67794 Silly question... did you set the PDFData string before attempting to deserialize? It should work given your code if the string is set correctly.

Comment: Yeah, PDFData is being setup correctly. I'm printing out the value from my JS before going to the Apex controller and the value itself is correct. After I made the changes you recommended the debug line stopped showing up - which is weird. The debug lines should be showing up regardless.